# How to use less variables with $_GET

Tags: php, javascript, html, url, get

I've noticed that instead of using:

`http://yoursite.com/index.php?page=4`

I could just use:

`http://yoursite.com/index.php?4`

How to do this in php and JavaScript?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example you have posted, now `4` is the key instead of value.

If you are passing ONLY one parameter via query string this is doable,otherwise you wont know in PHP what is what without a key for your parameter.

In the particular example you can get it like this in PHP

```
$id = null
if(!empty($_GET)){
    $keys = array_keys($_GET);

    // verify that the first key contains only digits, and use it as id
    // ctype_digit does not work here because the key is now an int so use is_numeric
    if(is_numeric($keys[0]))
        $id = $keys[0];
}
```

I do not know what do you want to do in Javascript here.

Also if you are trying to generate SEO friendly URLs I would suggest that you look into [URL Rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine).

Comment: That's not really a recommendation, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

```
$page = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```